# checking for detailed logs

Tags: support, login

I've been logged in consecutively for 97 days, and yesterday as i was checking my status, it changed to 1 :(. I was wondering if there is a way i can check a detailed log of my sign-ins / sign outs

Comment: Ouch. I lost my streak in Vegas, so at least I had a good excuse.

Comment: I really thought I was well within the 24 hours

Comment: I lost mine in Jamaica! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New feature:** If you click on the 'visited days' in your profile, it will bring up a calendar and show which day you visited (and missed):

[image]

Looking at your detailed logs, you did not access the site on Sunday, 11/07. Remember, the system "days" are in Universal time (UTC).

> 2010-11-08 12:52:11    user accessed site
>   2010-11-06 11:41:00    user accessed site
>   2010-11-06 11:40:53    login
>   2010-11-05 12:05:49    user accessed site

Comment: ah Darn, so I was off by 25 minutes?

Comment: @dassouki: 52 actually